# GIS Education Guide

Tags: education

I am a Computer Science graduate.  I have one year of experience in JAVA programming & I recently started working with GIS applications.  I found it so interesting that I would like to do my Post Graduate & PHD in a field related to GIS. Can anybody suggest some online courses, Professional Schools or Universities with a good reputation/curriculum?

Answer (score 3):

I understand that [COGS](http://www.cogs.ns.ca/Programs/) has a number of great programs and that you can also do work placement programs as part of the educational experience.  Not only does this give you some hands-on experience, it could actually lead to a job offer following your placement.  I don't know if they offer any online options "**specific to GIS**" but [HERE'S A LINK](http://www.onlinelearning.nscc.ca/) speciific to online learning options.

They have a great reputation.  I know a Geologist who graduated from one of their Post Graduate programs in GIS, and he had an exceptionally strong & diverse GIS skill set (programming languages, LIDAR analysis, 3D modeling, etc, etc).  There's also a bit of a course list [HERE](http://www.nscc.ca/Learning_Programs/Programs/ProgramListing.aspx?list=campus&camp=ANNAP). If you scroll to the bottom you can access the course list and a wealth of other information. There are a number of programs available, but here's a link to the course for a concentration in [Geographic Sciences](http://www.nscc.ca/learning_programs/programs/plandescr.aspx?prg=GEOS&pln=GEOSCIYR1) (just one of the many concentrations they offer).

If full time schooling is an option, you will receive a fantastic education here.  If not, I suggest you look in to their online and part-time options.  I hope this helps.

**ADDITIONAL SCHOOLS WITH STRONG PROGRAMS**

[Geomatics Institute at Fleming](http://flemingcollege.ca/geomatics-at-fleming/)

[Sault College - Applications Specialist](http://www.saultcollege.ca/programs/print/4018.htm)

Answer (score 1):

The NewMapsPlus program at U. of Kentucky focuses on open-source and web mapping. Seems to be focus on javascript and related libraries and Q rather than Esri stuff.

http://newmapsplus.uky.edu/new-maps-plus-programs-and-online-courses

Answer (score 0):

I personally found this site (https://www.e-education.psu.edu/geog485/node/152) to be extremely useful.

It emphasizes the python language as it pertains to mapping. Additionally a lot of powerful and rapid data analysis can be performed using it in combination with GIS software.